# How do you update existing records in Google Cloud Dataflow?

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Is it possible to update or insert new rows in an existing table using Google Cloud Dataflow?

Say for example I have the table below:

```
Book Table
BookId String(10)
Title String(50)
Content String(300)
Genre String(10)
```

And I have the following records already inside:

```
__________________________________________________
BookID     |   Title    | Content      | Genre   |
           |            |              |         |
1          | Deadlock   | Some Content |         |
2          | Arefureta  | Contentss    |         |
--------------------------------------------------
```

In this case I wanted my dataflow to populate the Genre column without affecting the current records.

How can I do this? Is this even possible? Or is there some sort of limitation from Google Cloud dataflow?

I wanted a result like this, after running the Dataflow:

```
__________________________________________________
BookID     |   Title    | Content      | Genre   |
           |            |              |         |
1          | Deadlock   | Some Content | Action  |
2          | Arefureta  | Contentss    |Adventure|
--------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: you want to update `Genre` column to existing records? Basically update statement

Comment: Can you specify what kind of table/database you're using? Otherwise the best I can do is direct you to the [API reference](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.22.0/) where you can find documentation for the IO you're using.